# We need to boost concentration and attention skills

Tags: collocations

I find "concentration and attention skills" weird because I suspect they are not skills. I would instead write:

> We need to practice concentration and increase our attention span.

What do you think? Are there better ways to express this idea?

Comment: Why do you say that they aren't skills.  Are some people better at concentrating than others?  Can the ability to concentrate be improved with practice? If so, it is a skill!

Comment: What is the source of the phrase "concentration and attention skills"  If you didn't write this yourself, please tell us where you read it.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is "improve my phrasing".  We can answer specific questions, but this is like proofreading/opinion.

Comment: @stangdon The original sentence is from a book of exam sample essays written by a Canadian. As I read it, questions about its language usage pop up in my head. How do you think the question can be asked in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase  "concentration and attention skills' Emphasizes that there are (in the opinion of the speaker) skills that can be used to improve the ability to concentrate and to focus attention. To rewrite this to

> We need to practice concentration and increase our attention span.

seems to change the meaning.  There might well be skills associated with "attention" other than lengthening the span, for example.

One might disagree with the original speaker, but that does not make the sentence ungrammatical.